# Блокировка ориентации экрана с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, orientation

Имеется ли возможность средствами javascript запретить смену ориентации экрана? CSS в моём случае не подходит. Пробовал Screen Orientation API, но в chrome не сработало, хотя пишут, что поддерживает. В консоль выводит предупреждение, что ппереход в полноэкранный режим возможен только по инициативе пользователя. А не в полноэкранном режиме `orientation.lock()` не работает.

```js
if (document.body.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    document.body.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    screen.orientation.lock('portrait')
        .then(() => console.log('locked'))
        .catch(() => console.log('fail'));
}
```

UPD
если на странице поселить элемент, с которым может взаимодействовать пользователь, выходит по клику в полноэкранный режим и работает screen.lock(), но для меня это не выход. Нужна блокировка со старта загрузки.

Comment: Таких легальных методов нет. Вот здесь подобное разбирали
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501510/blocking-device-rotation-on-mobile-web-pages

Comment: И вот еще посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634583/prevent-landscape-orientation-mobile-website

Comment: @РоманТатаринов видел всё это. Мне с transform: rotate() никак не подходит. А screen.orientation.lock() вполне легальный метод, только мешает требование полноэкранного режима.